# Prerequisites for some topics in Analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I'm confused about a course named "Topics in Modern Analysis" in a master program. **I need to know the prerequisites for this course in some details**.

About my skills: (1)I'm self-studying (2) I'm reading "Principle of Analysis by Rudin" (just finished the first 5 chapters) and "Linear algebra done right by Axler". Also, I exercise writing proofs.

**The course is described as follows:**

> Topics:
>
> 1- Basics of functional analysis: metric, norm, scalar product,
>   Banach space, Hilbert space, orthonormal basis, orthogonal complement,
>   separable Hilbert space, formal Fourier series, operators, properties
>   of operators, application of the basic concepts to integral
>   transforms, to dierential and nonlinear equations
>
> 2- Application to the Wavelet Transform: numerical approximation of
>   functions, advantages and disadvantages of individual methods, Haar
>   transformation, continuous wavelet transformation, discrete wavelet
>   transformation - multiscale analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to continue *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* to about Chapter 9 and then, I would assume, read either the real analysis half of *Real and Complex Analysis* by Rudin or some other source for Lebesgue integration. However, it would be best to ask your future instructor this question, because it's not clear how much background you'd need in Lebesgue integration or at what level of difficulty. The wording "proving (at a higher level of abstraction)" suggests to me that the course may not be at a very high level.

Comment: What do you mean by “the real analysis half of R&C analysis by Rudin”; what chapters?. This book needs chapters [1 to 7] of Rudin’s Principles of Analysis according to its preface. Thus, can I skip 8 & 9?

Comment: By the "real analysis half," I mean Chapters 1 through 9. I suggested Chapter 8 because it gives additional background in analysis, particularly on Fourier series. I'm not sure whether everything on Fourier series in *Principles* is repeated in *Real and Complex Analysis*. Chapter 9 of *Principles* is on multivariable differentiation. The material on this strictly required in *Real and Complex Analysis* is repeated in Chapter 7 of that book, but I think it's best to have some familiarity beforehand. You can try without Chapters 8 and 9 of *Principles* if you're in a hurry.

Comment: Quoting your answer "Real&Complex Analysis.....or some other source for Lebesgue integration". I'm not sure what exactly is needed from "Real&Complex Analysis by Rudin" (it is 2-semester graduate text). Can you elaborate on this (like chapters wise or other focused books)?

Comment: I suggested Chapters 1 through 9 of both of Rudin's books. In the case of *Real and Complex Analysis*, this is what I referred to as "the real analysis half."

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm also not part of the master program to ask the tutor. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I could have been clearer in distinguishing between the two books in my comment. I missed the part where you said you'd been reading Axler, so I'm removing the part of my answer about linear algebra.